# Make every div the size of the viewport

Tags: html, css

I want to have CSS that makes each div the size of the screen and then whenever the user scrolls the next div will snap into view. There's a JavaScript library that does the latter but I can't remember the name. As for getting every div the size of the screen I have tried the following but to no avail.

```
<div>Div Content</div>

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`vw` and `vh`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) to make an element the size of the viewport:

```
div {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Divs are block elements and 100% of the width of the parent by default. As for the height, use `100vh` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are new units in css3 which makes it easier to assign viewport-width and viewport-height.

They are vw,vh.

```
div{
 width:100vh;
 height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `div` are direct child of body, then `height:100%` can be calculated from the viewport if every parents are set the same.

Why? : `%` needs a value from the parent to be calculated and applied.

`width` is here not necessary for block elements and can even become a problem if `margin`, `border` or `padding` are added.

```css
html,
body,
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Div Content</div>
<div>Div Content</div>
<div>Div Content</div>
```